# попарно вывести элементы двух и более списков

Tags: python, python-3.x, алгоритм, list, коллекции

есть 2 или более списков:

```
list1 = [a1, b1, c1]
list2 = [a2, b2, c2]
list3 = [a3, b3, c3]
```

Необходимо:

```
result_a = [a1, a2, a3]
result_b = [b1, b2, b3]
result_c = [c1, c2, c3]
```

Comment: zip(list1, list2, list3)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Matrix Transpose in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4937491/4279)

Comment: `for result in zip(*lists): print(*result)`

Comment: есть ли такой же способ, но если кол-во элементов неограниченно большое

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list1 = ['a1', 'b1', 'c1']
list2 = ['a2', 'b2', 'c2']
list3 = ['a3', 'b3', 'c3']


result_a, result_b, result_c = zip(list1, list2, list3)
print(result_a)  # ('a1', 'a2', 'a3')
print(result_b)  # ('b1', 'b2', 'b3')
print(result_c)  # ('c1', 'c2', 'c3')
```

Если нужно получить именно списки (а не кортежи), тогда можно каждый элемент привести к `list` через `map`:

```
result_a, result_b, result_c = map(list, zip(list1, list2, list3))
print(result_a)  # ['a1', 'a2', 'a3']
print(result_b)  # ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
print(result_c)  # ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']
```

---

**PS.** `map(list, zip(list1, list2, list3))` отлично заменяется генераторами списков: `(list(x) for x in zip(list1, list2, list3))`

Answer (score 1):

Встроенная функция [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#zip) соединяет несколько листов а кортежи:

```
result_a, result_b, result_c = zip(list1, list2, list3)
```